# mongo find selector causes unmatching results to be returns

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

`userLink_titles = Entries.find({ _id:"bxSbMgszYxbCqDonF"})`

returns:

```
  docs: Object
    CBqHrJvTE8xz7u2Rz: Object
      _id: "CBqHrJvTE8xz7u2Rz"
      author: "AHSwfYgeGmur9oHzu"
    Q8m7PMbQr62E3A73f: Object
      _id: "Q8m7PMbQr62E3A73f"
      author: "AHSwfYgeGmur9oHzu"
    bxSbMgszYxbCqDonF: Object
      _id: "bxSbMgszYxbCqDonF"
      author: "AHSwfYgeGmur9oHzu"
```

As you can see it returns the correct document but it also returns incorrect documents.

findOne: `userLink_titles = Entries.findOne({ _id:"bxSbMgszYxbCqDonF"})` works as expected and only returns the correct document.

I would use the findOne except that the end intention is to make the _id selector an array such that find would return the documents for all documents that match the _id selectors in the array.

Bonus Points:

Let's say I wanted to retrieve the titles of a set of articles, where the references to those articles (the _ids of the Articles in their Articles collection) have been saved in a user collection.

So effectively I would retrieve the Article references from the user collection, and use those references to retrieve the titles of Articles from the Articles collection.

What would the code/pseudo code look like for that? Something like the following (I am assuming the below is a complete bastardization of some best practices for querying/retrieving records)

```
user_profile = Users.findOne({username : "Frank"});
user_saved_articles_ids = user_profile.findOne({saved_articles_ids});
userLinks = Articles.find({ _id:user_saved_articles_ids});
userLinksTitles = Articles.find({titles});
```

Comment: Your search for `_id` is matching at the top level of the document.  From your result it appears that the incorrect documents you are referring to appear to be embedded in the `docs` array as (_id, author pairs)?

Comment: i hosted an example site here: http://protobrewui.meteor.com

The find operation I mention was something I ran from the console:

For the hosted site, if you run in the console:
userLink_titles = Entries.find({ _id:"HpjkkBJXWTxFEgrc9"}) I would think you would only get the Articles back. Instead as you are saying it is matching at a level higher levle. How do I then only retrieve the part of the document that matches the selector _id, or is that not legit in this type of query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to inspect the results of a query in the console, use `Entries.find(...).fetch()`

`Entries.find()` returns a [cursor](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_collection_cursor), which is a construct used to render lists efficiently, so that only the entries that change need to be re-rendered. Returning cursors from helpers on which you use `{{#each}}` will lead to more responsive apps.

Answer (score 2):

For those interested in the bonus question, you want MongoDB's [$in operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/in/).

If this will be used in a publish method on the server then you may want to check out [publish-with-relations](https://github.com/erundook/meteor-publish-with-relations).

Something like the function below would be an efficient way to retrieve the information.  It makes two calls to the database.  Using the `fields` parameter prevents unnecessary data from being sent between the db and the webserver.

```
/**
 * Titles of a User's saved articles
 * 
 * @method getSavedTitles
 * @param {String} username
 * @return {Array} a list of article titles
 */
function getSavedTitles (username) {
  var user,
      ids,
      linkedArticles,
      titles;

  user = Users.findOne({username: username}, 
                       {fields:{ _id:0, profile:1 }});

  if (!user || !user.profile) {
    throw new Meteor.Error(500, 'Missing user profile');
  }

  ids = user.profile.savedArticleIds;

  if (!ids || !_.isArray(ids)) {
    throw new Meteor.Error(500, 'Missing saved article ids');
  }

  linkedArticles = Articles.find({_id: {$in: ids}},
                        {fields:{ _id:0, title:1 }});

  titles = _.pluck(linkedArticles.fetch(), "title");

  return titles;

}  // end getSavedTitles
```

Comment: i wish i could mark two right answers... post your answer here and I'll give it the love: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137089/mongodb-meter-js-how-to-search-if-a-value-is-in-a-document